Is there a medial quandle for which the relation $\sim$ defined by $a\sim b$ iff $a\ast b=a$ is not an equivalence relation?
Definitions:

A quandle is a set $Q$ with a binary operation $\ast$ satisfying three axioms, for all $a,b,c$ in $Q$:

$a\ast a=a$.
There exist a unique $x$ such that $x\ast a=b$.
$(a\ast b)\ast c=(a\ast c)\ast(b\ast c)$.



Suppose $(Q,\ast)$ is a quandle. It is called a medial quandle if $$(a\ast b)\ast (c\ast d)=(a\ast c)\ast(b\ast d)$$
for all $a,b,c,d$ in $Q$.

Does someone know any medial quandle $(Q,\ast)$ such that if I define a relation $\sim$ on $Q$ by $a\sim b$ iff $a\ast b=a$,then this relation is not an equivalence relation? I know that any Alexander quandle, which is the most common examples of medial quandle that people give, have the property that the relation defined above is always an equivalence relation. I want to know if there exist medial quandle that does not satisfy this property. This question is related to some question in knot theory that I am doing.
By the way, Alexander quandle is any abelian group with an automorphism f by taking the operation x ∗ y = (1 − f )(x) + f (y).

What is an Alexander quandle?

It seems to me that the first two axioms imply that $a*b = a$ iff $a = b$, so maybe I'm missing something.

Sorry, I made a typo. The 2nd axiom should be “there exist an unique x such that x*a=b.”
